# GLSL Parallax mapping issue

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I wrote parallax mapping shader in GLSL but it is working wrong. In some places it shows correct image with good bump but in other positions it becomes flat. It's became most flat when I moving camera father than platform(forward)

```
#version 120
varying vec3 pos;
varying vec3 normal;
varying vec2 tc;
varying vec3 color;
uniform vec3 camera;

void main(void)
{
    pos = (-gl_Vertex.xyz + camera);
    tc = gl_MultiTexCoord0.xy;
    normal = normalize(gl_Normal);
    color = gl_Color.xyz;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}

#version 120
uniform sampler2D normal_map;
uniform sampler2D diffuse_map;
uniform sampler2D displacement;
uniform float mode;

varying vec2 tc;
varying vec3 pos;

void main(void)
{
    vec3 lightPos = vec3( 0.0, -45.0, -40.0);
    vec4 color;
    if (mode > 1)
    {
        vec3 eyeVec = normalize(pos);
        vec2 eyeProj = normalize(eyeVec.xz);
        float curHeight = texture2D(displacement, tc).r - 0.5;
        vec2 trTc = tc - (eyeProj) * curHeight * 0.035;
        vec3 normal = normalize(texture2D(normal_map, trTc).xzy*2.0 - 1.0);
        color = texture2D(diffuse_map, trTc) * dot( normalize(pos - lightPos), normal) * 1.0;
        color.w = 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        vec3 normal = normalize(texture2D(normal_map, tc).xzy*2.0 - 1.0);
        color = texture2D(diffuse_map, tc) * dot( normalize(pos - lightPos), normal) * 1.0;
    }
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

I can't even imagine where can be mistake. I was experimenting with camera and vertex values but it is not help;

Comment: can we see a screenshot of the issue ?

Comment: Offcourse http://habrastorage.org/storage3/41e/47c/2a4/41e47c2a4827f9bb4f0b05e37aeb87d2.jpg

Comment: In what positions is it flat? Parallax mapping has a disadvantage, that the surface looks flat, if it's near perpendicular to the screen...